# Преобразование десятичного числа в сумму степеней двойки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу написать программу, которая будет преобразовывать десятичное число в сумму степеней двойки с последующей заменой слагаемых 1, 2, 4(и т. д.) на текст.

Пока столкнулся с проблемой:
на вход подается десятичное число, которое тут же преобразуется в двоичное:

```
a = bin(int(input('Enter a unit flags number here:')))
print(a)
```

Если ввожу число 123, программа выдает:

0b1111011

Дальше я хочу преобразовать это число в строку, избавиться от первых двух значений(0b) и выполнить реверс с последующим преобразованием в массив, для удобной работы по индексам.

Вот только стандартное str(a) преобразует бинарную запись обратно в десятичное число(123) и на данный момент я не нашел как это обойти.

Как все это должно выглядеть в идеале:

Запуск.
Enter a unit flags number here:.
Ввожу число, например 123.
Программа выдает:

```
1 text1
2 text2
8 text4
16 text5
32 text6
64 text7
```

т.е. за каждой степенью двойки закреплен свой уникальный текст.

Comment: приведите в вопросе пример того что вы хотите получить в итоге

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bits = list(map(int, reversed(bin(123)[2:])))
```

Преобразуем 123 в двоичное, отрезаем `0b`, переворачиваем, кладем в массив, каждый элемент преобразуем из строки в число. На выходе получаем `[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

```
for i, b in enumerate(bits):
    print((2**i)*b, dict[(2**i)*b])
```

`dict` должен выглядеть так – `{*степень двойки*:*соответствующий текст*}`, например `dict[64] = 'blablabla'`

Comment: все работает, спасибо. Вот только почему - то не выходит в последнем цикле, если в массиве находится 0 - пропускать это значение и не выводить. пробовал через добавление if b==0: continue в цикл for

Comment: в итоге реализовал через if (2 ** i) * b == 0: continue, что, как по мне, очень топорно. В чем разница условий if b==0 и if if (2 ** i) * b == 0 так и не понял, что в первом если b = 0, условие должно выполниться, что во втором, перемножение числа и нуля даст ноль.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте метод `format()`:

```
'{:08b}'.format(a)
```

Bывод:

> '1111011'

(если в переменной `а` было значение `0b1111011` или - что это это же самое - `123`).

Comment: это ведь и близко не ответ на вопрос

Comment: @pinguin - Это ответ на требование "Вот только стандартное str(a) преобразует бинарную запись обратно в десятичное число(123) и на данный момент я не нашел как это обойти."